# Android What Event Is fired when user click on an EditText box?

Tags: android

I am trying to prefill an EditText widget with some instr. but erase the moment the user clicks in the box so they start leftmost point? I tried registering onClickListener(), onKeyListener but I was not able to capture this? Thanks  What can I register to detect this first click within the text editing area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without listening for an event.  In your EditText element in your layout.xml file, you can set an attribute *android:hint*.

```
<EditText 
  android:hint="Write Caption" <!-- This line -->
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try using a focus listener.

EDIT: try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html